# Get description from code in dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-post

I have a dropdown in my webapp in which there are two values; code and description. In the input field i can filter them. When i click on the item i want i send a http `POST` request (in `angularjs`). This request send all values in json format. So i send in POST, code and the description. After the submit, i have the server response that returns only the code. This is correct and i need mantain this kind of structure. What i would do is show in the input field, after submit, the description that is "connected" to that code. Here i created a simultion (without send url of course).

http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/26/

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <form data-ng-submit="send()">
            <div class="uk-form-row uk-width-1-1" data-ng-repeat="items in inputList.getinputList">
                <input ng-model='item.value' type="text" placeholder="Choose"/>
                <!-- WORKS OK -->
                <div class="uk-parent" data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click'}">
                    <a href="">Nav item - Works OK</a>
                    <div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-navbar" style="top:50px">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr data-ng-repeat="item in numberList.getList | filter:item.value" ng-click="setSelected(item)">
                                <td>{{item.first}}</td>
                                <td>{{item.last}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button>Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular part:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);


function MyCtrl($scope, $http) {
    var url = "http://....";

    $scope.item={}
    $scope.numberList={}
    $scope.numberList.getList=[{'first':'1','last':'skeet'},{'first':'2','last':'shaikh'},{'first':'3','last':'game'}]

    $scope.inputList={}
    $scope.inputList.getinputList=[{'firstA':'AAA','lastB':'BBBB'}]

    $scope.idSelectedVote = null;
    $scope.setSelected = function (idSelectedVote) {

        $scope.idSelectedVote = idSelectedVote;
        $scope.item.value=idSelectedVote.last;
        //alert(idSelectedVote);
    };

    $scope.send = function() {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: {
                datas: $scope.numberList.getList
            }

        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.result = data;

        }).error(function(data, status) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        });

    };
}
```

As i wrote, when i click "send" button i inject a http POST request that sends the datas inside the input text to a url as json. The server send me a response without the description but only the code. I need from that code go back to the correct description

Comment: What's the question? Also, please post code AS WELL AS fiddle

Comment: Ok i'm going to edit the quest

Comment: What is processing the data on the server? That's what we need to see - you're showing what is sending ok but not what is actually processing then sending back the incorrect data

Comment: i have not the server side. By the way, the server sending back the correct data. It send back the code. My problem is that i need be able to go back to the description in some way from the code that the server returns. Is it possible?